# pandas, store multiple datasets in an h5 file with pd.to_hdf

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have two dataframes,

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[0,2,3,2],'col2':[1,0,0,1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col12':[0,1,2,1],'col22':[1,1,1,1]})
```

Now `df1.to_hdf('nameoffile.h5', 'key_to_store','w',table=True)`
successully stores `df1` but I want to also store `df2` to the same file, but If I try the same method then `df1` will just be over written. When I try to load it and I check the keys I only see the info of `df2`. How can I store both `df1` and `df2` in the same h5 file as a table ?

Comment: by default `to_hdf` appends so if you remove `'w'` it should append `df2.to_hdf('nameoffile.h5', 'key_to_store'',table=True)` see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf)

Comment: great! works like magic, ty!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `'w'` which overwrites, by default the mode is `'a'` so you can just do:

```
df2.to_hdf('nameoffile.h5', 'key_to_store', table=True, mode='a')
```

Check the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf

Comment: I was wondering if you have any insights to share about this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38283279/combining-huge-h5-files-with-multiple-datasets-into-one-with-odo

Comment: In newer versions: `df2.to_hdf('nameoffile.h5', 'key_to_store', format="table", mode='a')`

Answer (score 1):

I have used this in the past without issue:

```
store = pd.HDFStore(path_to_hdf)
store[new_df_name] = df2
store.close()
```

So in your case you could try:

```
store = pd.HDFStore(path_to_hdf)
store['df1'] = df1
store['df2'] = df2
store.close()
```

I used this in a system where a user could store layouts for microtiter plate experiments. The first time they saved a layout the hdf file was created and subsequent layouts could then be appended to the file.

N.B. I have set `pd.set_option('io.hdf.default.format', 'table')` at the beginning of my program.